# Plot general solutions

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to plot the general solutions of the following pde:

```
pde = \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({t}\)]\(u[x, t]\)\) ==  t (u[x, t] + (
 2^(1/3) u[x, t]^2)/(-2 u[x, t]^3 + A + 
   Sqrt[-4 u[x, t]^3 A + A^2])^(
 1/3) + (-2 u[x, t]^3 + A + Sqrt[-4 u[x, t]^3 A + A^2])^(1/3)/2^(
 1/3))
ics = {u[x, 1] == x};
sol = DSolve[pde && ics, u[x, t], {x, t}][[1, 1]]
```

Generating the code, we get

```
    u[x, t] -> 
 InverseFunction[
   Inactive[Integrate][(A - 2 K[2]^3 + Sqrt[A] Sqrt[A - 4 K[2]^3])^(
     1/3)/(2 2^(1/3) K[2]^2 + 
      2 K[2] (A - 2 K[2]^3 + Sqrt[A] Sqrt[A - 4 K[2]^3])^(1/3) + 
      2^(2/3) (A - 2 K[2]^3 + Sqrt[A] Sqrt[A - 4 K[2]^3])^(2/3)), {K[
       2], 1, #1}] &][
  t^2/4 + 1/
    4 (-1 + 4 Inactive[
         Integrate][(A - 2 K[2]^3 + Sqrt[A] Sqrt[A - 4 K[2]^3])^(
        1/3)/(2 2^(1/3) K[2]^2 + 
         2 K[2] (A - 2 K[2]^3 + Sqrt[A] Sqrt[A - 4 K[2]^3])^(1/3) + 
         2^(2/3) (A - 2 K[2]^3 + Sqrt[A] Sqrt[A - 4 K[2]^3])^(
          2/3)), {K[2], 1, x}])]
```

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica does not give an explicit solution, because it can't integrate the integrals.

In addition, even it it did, you can't plot the solution since $A$ is not known. Even giving $A$ a numerical value, the integrals remain unevaluated.

Instead, why not plot the solution using NDSolve?

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == 
  t*(u[x, t] + (2^(1/3) u[x, t]^2)/(-2 u[x, t]^3 + A + 
         Sqrt[-4 u[x, t]^3 A + A^2])^(1/3) + (-2 u[x, t]^3 + A + 
         Sqrt[-4 u[x, t]^3 A + A^2])^(1/3)/2^(1/3))
ics = u[x, 1] == x
A = 1;
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, ics}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}];
Animate[Plot[sol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], {t, 0, 1, .01}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

pde = D[u[x, t], t] == t*(u[x, t] + (2^(1/3) u[x, t]^2)/
       (-2 u[x, t]^3 + A + Sqrt[-4 u[x, t]^3 A + A^2])^(1/3) +
      (-2 u[x, t]^3 + A + Sqrt[-4 u[x, t]^3 A + 
    A^2])^(1/3)/2^(1/3));
ics = {u[x, 1] == x};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[pde && ics, u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, {A}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[u[x, t][av] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, t, u})],
 {{av, 1, "A"}, {1, 5, 10, 50, 100}},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {av}]
```

[image]